# C# method multiple constraints with "new"

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

I'm trying to define a method that has multiple constraints where the `T` type is able to be used as a constructor:

```
private void GetData<T, OType>(string url, string token1, string token2, Action<T, SqlConnection, SqlTransaction> bulkInsert, string user = null, string pwd = null) 
    where T : JsonElements<OType>, new
    where OType : class 
{
    var thing = T();
```

I'm getting an error on the `new` part though saying

> ) expected

What's the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `new()`, not just `new`. This is a visual clue to a parameter-less constructor.

Also, you have to use `new T()` when assigning `thing`.